# Extract Parameter (sub-string) from URL GROK Pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I have ELK running for log analysis. I have everything working. There are just a few tweaks I would like to make. To all the ES/ELK Gods in stackoverflow, I'd appreciate any help on this. I'd gladly buy you a cup of coffee! :D

Example:

URL: /origina-www.domain.com/this/is/a/path?page=2

First I would like to get the entire path as seen above.

Second, I would like to get just the path before the parameter: /origina-www.domain.com/this/is/a/path

Third, I would like to get just the parameter: ?page=2

Fourth, I would like to make the timestamp on the logfile be the main time stamp on kibana. Currently, the timestamp kibana is showing is the date and time the ES was processed.

This is what a sample entry looks like:

```
2016-10-19 23:57:32 192.168.0.1 GET /origin-www.example.com/url 200 1144 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "-" "-"
```

Here's my config:

```
if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => ["message", "%{IP:client}\s+%{WORD:method}\s+%{URIPATHPARAM:request}\s+%{NUMBER:bytes}\s+%{NUMBER:duration}\s+%{USER-AGENT}\s+%{QS:referrer}\s+%{QS:agent}%{GREEDYDATA}"]
          }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a" ]
      locale => "en"
    }   
}
```

ES Version: 5.0.1
Logstash Version: 5.0
Kibana: 5.0

UPDATE: I was actually able to solve it by using:

```
grok {
          match => ["message", "%{IP:client}\s+%{WORD:method}\s+%{URIPATHPARAM:request}\s+%{NUMBER:bytes}\s+%{NUMBER:duration}\s+%{USER-AGENT}\s+%{QS:referrer}\s+%{QS:agent}%{GREEDYDATA}"]
        }
        grok {
            match => [ "request", "%{GREEDYDATA:uri_path}\?%{GREEDYDATA:uri_query}" ]
        }

        kv {
            source => "uri_query"
            field_split => "&"
            target => "query"
        }
```

Comment: kv would have been my suggestion, you should post your solution as a self-answer to help others with similar questions in the future

Comment: @WillBarnwell How do I do that? I'm kind of new here and still learning how SO works. :)

Comment: Btw, @WillBarnwell I did have one last question in there, the fourth one about changing the time stamp of kibana to use the actual time and date of each log entry. Maybe you can help me on that one? :) Would very much appreciate as I am learning the ropes on ES.

Comment: For the date : You can use the TIMESTAMP_ISO8601 pattern to grab the `2016-10-19 23:57:32` string. Then you can use the date filter with this pattern : "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the actual `timestamp` of your log entry rather than the indexed time, you could use the `date` and `mutate` plugins as such to override the existing `timestamp` value. You could have your `logstash` filter look, something like this:

```
       //filtering your log file
        grok {
                patterns_dir => ["/pathto/patterns"] <--- you could have a pattern file with such expression LOGTIMESTAMP %{YEAR}%{MONTHNUM}%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} if you have to change the timestamp format.
                match => { "message" => "^%{LOGTIMESTAMP:logtimestamp}%{GREEDYDATA}" }          
        }
        //overriding the existing timestamp with the new field logtimestamp
        mutate {
                add_field => { "timestamp" => "%{logtimestamp}" }
                remove_field => ["logtimestamp"]
        }
        //inserting the timestamp as UTC
        date   {
                match => [ "timestamp" , "ISO8601" , "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
                target => "timestamp"
                locale => "en"
                timezone => "UTC"
        }
```

You could follow up [Question](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-i-replace-logstash-timestamp-with-timestamp-of-my-logfile/32649/16) for more as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
grok {
    match => ["message", "%{IP:client}\s+%{WORD:method}\s+%{URIPATHPARAM:request}\s+%{NUMBER:bytes}\s+%{NUMBER:duration}\s+%{USER-AGENT}\s+%{QS:referrer}\s+%{QS:agent}%{GREEDYDATA}"]
}

grok {
    match => [ "request", "%{GREEDYDATA:uri_path}\?%{GREEDYDATA:uri_query}" ]
}

kv {
    source => "uri_query"
    field_split => "&"
    target => "query"
}
```